# What are the correct procedures when someone accidentally touches high voltage live cable and is getting electrocuted?

Tags: safety, electrocution

Suppose a family member accidentally touches high voltage live cable and is getting electrocuted in the toilet while he is installing lights. The problem with electricity is risk of conduction and trying to save him will get one killed as well.

What are the correct procedures to save him?

Comment: Anyone installing lights should not do so unless they are proficient in the safety precautions and that means disabling the electricity. I wonder what Darwin would say?

Comment: Somebody once told me a way was, to tackle them away from the wires.

Comment: In the Navy, they taught the first action is to try to get them clear with a wooden stick or such.

Comment: Getting 'electrocuted in the toilet' sounds like some decent comedy, perhaps the correct procedure would be to grab your camera and take some footage.

Comment: De-energize the circuit or move the person using a non-conductive object. For example, in the specific situation you mention, turning off the light switch would de-energize the circuit.

Comment: The truth is that 120 and 240 V circuits seldom cause the type of electrocution you are thinking of where the muscles spasmodically contract and cause the victim to be unable to let go of the conductor. Usually you just get a shock and maybe pass out and then hopefully you wake up and are OK afterwards.

Comment: Assuming you're not barefoot, give them a good kick for being that dumb and/or sloppy.

Comment: @Spehro-Pefhany: Preferably a flying kick; it's safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ensure your own safety, and call 911.
2. IF you have access to the power cutoff, use it to kill the live circuit (the 911 person will likely tell you to do this.) This is not only for rescuing the victim, but also safety for you and the first responders coming to help.
3. Whether or not you’ve killed the circuit (how do you know for sure?) use a wooden pole or other non-conducting object to separate the victim from the shock hazard. Do not use your bare hands. Grabbing the victim by their clothing is risky - could be wet.

High voltage from a downed power line poses an extra hazard of stray currents, so it’s important to keep your distance from any loose wires making contact with the ground.

4. Once you've moved the victim clear of the hazard, check for clear airway, breathing and heartbeat (the ‘ABC’ of first aid.) Initiate CPR if necessary. Apply pressure to any large bleeding wounds.

This Wikihow has more details. https://www.wikihow.com/Treat-a-Victim-of-Electrical-Shock

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upvoted. I'm not sure how long electrocution takes to kill a person. If 911 ambulance arrives after 15 minutes, is it likely that the person would have died?

Comment: It depends on the exact path the shock current took through the victim's body, and how large it was. If it stopped their heart, permanent brain damage can happen if they go longer than 3 minutes or so without help. On the other hand, if you free them quickly and do CPR, even poorly, it may be enough to save the person until EMS arrives.

Comment: If you call 911, they'll even give you a crash course in CPR

Comment: Cutting the power after calling emergency services sounds a bit harsh hahaha

Comment: Surely step 1 should be moved after steps 2 and 3? Presuming they are quick. In fact, surely you should even check their breathing and heartbeat before calling 911?

Comment: No, summoning help is the #1 go-to in any rescue training. They not only can do advanced life support, but also help with scene safety. They can also walk you through CPR and patient assessment as you’re helping the victim.

Comment: It’s really, really important to consider your own safety first. If you also get electrocuted by trying to be ‘quick’ you are no longer a rescuer, you are now a victim. This seems harsh, but it’s standard first responder protocol.

Comment: It is not engineering. But I agree with hacktastical, too, FWIW. But in this SPECIFIC CASE, turning off the light is safe.

Comment: If you don't call 911 (emergency services) and start to help, and come to harm while helping, who will call 911 for you?

Answer (score 4):

The health and safety answer is to shut off the power and then deal with the medical issues.

There is another answer but it depends critically on the knowledge and judgement of the person carrying out the action. This is to remove the victim from the power using an insulating material. In this case as it is a lighting circuit the highest voltage likely to be there is 240V. So a piece of construction timber or a pair of insulating gloves should be sufficient. The knowledge and judgement plays into knowing what you are dealing with in terms of risk (how big is the voltage) and how to mitigate it (properties of insulators) so this can not be recommended as a course of action for all and sundry.

Comment: In this specific case as the family member who is installing the light is likely to be the most 'competent'  shut the power off.

Answer (score 1):

The person should be removed from contact with electricity fast as possible. If find wooden stick complicated, you may pull, using clothes. But use one hand, with second hand do not touch anything. And stand on some isolator. Do not touch the body. Once I got zapped with 347V, but managed get out with light skin burns. The health damage is depends on lot conditions. Wet place is worst, working on live wires is stupid.